# Trying to switch logo in header with jquery to add/remove class

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically I have a header on my site that goes from transparent to background white when you start to scroll down. It adds a class header-fixed when it starts scrolling. I am trying to switch between two logos when the header is acive with header-fixed or isn't. Here is the jQuery I have right now that I can't get to work:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        if( $('#masthead').hasClass('header-fixed') ) {
            $('.bdanzer-fixed').addClass('bdanzer-show');
        } else {
            $('.bdanzer-fixed').removeClass('bdanzer-show');
        }
    });
```

edit, adding HTML:

```
<img class="bdanzer-normal" src="https://dummytext">
                <img class="bdanzer-fixed" src="https://dummytext">
```

Comment: You must already have a function that runs when the page is scrolled. Put this code in that function.

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready()` is called only once after DOM is ready. You just need to handle `scroll` event instead of `ready`:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if ($('#masthead').hasClass('header-fixed')) {
        $('.bdanzer-fixed').addClass('bdanzer-show');
    } else {
        $('.bdanzer-fixed').removeClass('bdanzer-show');
    }
});
```

But it's not good to handle `scroll` in one place to add one class, and then handle `scroll` to look for this class and add another class to another element. Better to have only one `scroll` handler, which will do everything you need to do on scroll, and add/remove all necessary classes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried that but doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @Bdanzer please, try to apply `scroll` handler to `$(window)` instead of `$(document)`.

Answer (score 1):

Could also be simplified using the toggleClass function:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
    var hasClass = $('#masthead').hasClass('header-fixed'));
        $('.bdanzer-fixed').toggleClass('bdanzer-show', hasClass );
});
```